# Problem with mount namespaces under Fedora

Tags: linux, mount, virtualization, container

I've run into an odd problem regarding mount namespaces on Linux.  I have two systems, both X86_64 running kernel 3.2.3-2 under Fedora 16.  I am attempting to mount a `tmpfs` filesystem in a child namespace created using the `unshare` command:

```
unshare -m /bin/bash
```

From the man page:

```
   mount namespace
          mounting and unmounting filesystems will not affect rest of  the
          system (CLONE_NEWNS flag),
```

On one system, this works as expected.  That is, if I start with this:

```
# ls /mnt
file1 file2 file3
```

And then mount a `tmpfs` filesystem over `/mnt` in a child namespace:

```
# PS1="child# ' unshare -m /bin/bash
child# mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt
```

The contents of `/mnt` are masked in the child namespace:

```
child# ls /mnt
child#
```

But continue to be visible in the parent:

```
# ls /mnt
file1 file2 file3
```

On the second system, the exact same sequence of commands will result in a mount that is visible in the parent namespace as well as in the child namespace.  In other words, it appears that the `unshare` command is not actually resulting in a separate mount namespace.

I am not aware of any substantial differences between the two systems.  One is running a desktop environment, the other is not.  SELinux is disabled on both systems.

I'm looking for any suggestions as to what could be causing this difference in behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check to see if the sandbox service is running.

```
systemctl status sandbox.service
```

If so, turn it off, reboot, and try again.  This worked for me.

Comment: You, sir, win the prize.  It looks as if simply running `mount --make-rprivate /` will undo the effects of `/etc/rc.s/init.d/sandbox`.  Now I need to figure out if the sandbox script is necessary given that I'm not using pam_namespace...

Answer (score 3):

@John got the answer, but I wanted to provide some additional documentation here to reflect why the behavior of the two systems was different.

The `sandbox` script (`/etc/rc.d/init.d/sandbox`) recursively set the `shared` flag on all mounts on the system by running:

```
mount --make-rshared /
```

The comments in the `sandbox` script read:

> description: sandbox, xguest and other apps that want to use
>   pam_namespace
>                  require this script be run at boot.  This service script does
>                  not actually run any service but sets up:
>                  / to be shared by any app that starts a separate namespace
>                  If you do not use sandbox, xguest or pam_namespace you can turn
>                  this service off.

Because the tools referenced here are all GUI applications, the `sandbox` script is only enabled for runlevel 5.  Of the two systems I am working with, one is a desktop -- hence it starts up in runlevel 5 and gets the `sandbox` script by default -- while the other is a headless server booting to runlevel 3.

Answer (score 1):

I've been seeing the same issue.  Try a

```
mount --make-private /mnt
```

before the

```
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt
```

Also look at the source of the seunshare command to see how they do it.

Comment: In order for the `mount --make-private /mnt` command to complete, I need to run `mount -o bind /mnt /mnt` first (since /mnt is not a mountpoint otherwise).  This gets me something that works as intended, but still leaves me at a loss as to why one system works and the other doesn't.  This is also unfortunate because it requires the parent namespace to know in advance any mounts that will be performed by the child namespace, which would seem to defeat some of the advantages of mount namespaces.

Comment: I added [bug 788221](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=788221) to Fedora in the hopes with someone more familiar with the internals will comment on things.