# A process, run as root, when performing mount, is mounting for `self`, how to make the mount global?

Tags: filesystems, arch-linux, mount, namespace

I'm mounting a share from within process'es context. That, ultimately, mounts the object on a [`per-process namespace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html#NOTES) basis, rendering it invisible for the rest of the system.

The problem is partially related to [Problem with mount namespaces under Fedora](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31050/problem-with-mount-namespaces-under-fedora), just that I need it the other way around.

The process is Apache (httpd) running as root.

Running process as root, how do I mount globally from within process'es context?
Or, what actions I have to take prior to mounting from process, to make them global?

**Update:**
So far, I've attempted working with `--make-shared`, `--make-private` and `--bind` but to no avail. Cannot make actions to propagate outside process namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having posted this all around the *globe*, a user (hiciu) in Arch Linux forum did provide [the solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1343315#p1343315).

Apparently it's the systemd service that had [`PrivateTmp=true`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=):

> ...If true, sets up a new file system namespace for the executed processes...

Removing the option did fix the issue.

You can learn more about adventures to resolving the issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19682810/393406).